# Why was the onOptionsItemSelected method/function changed from using a switch-case statement to an if block?

Tags: android

I am programming in Android Studio and I was wondering why they changed the implementation of the `onOptionsItemSelected` to using an `if condition` where the statement would check the passed id instead of a `switch case` block that it used to do in Eclipse? I'm not sure if it still used the switch case statement in Android Studio.

The `onOptionsItemSelected` method used to look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.id1:
            //blah blah blah
            break;

        case R.id.id2: 
            //test
            break;

    };
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And now it looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.id1) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Does anyone know why they changed it? Are there advantages in using an if-else block over a switch case block when comparing integers (because ids are basically integers).

I doubt that Google decided to use an if-else statement for this function if it did not have its merits or advantages over the "old style" of a switch case block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it doesn't matter whether you use `if-else` or `switch`, both will accomplish the same thing.

There is one circumstance where you cannot use `switch`, and that is if the id values (e.g. `R.id.id1`) are defined and used in a library module. This is because resource names in library modules get generated as `public static` instead of `public static final` in the `R.java` file, so they are no longer compile-time constant expressions and thus cannot be used as cases for `switch`.

Comment: But what if they're just defined in the xml file? Would they still encounter the same circumstance? And with that circumstance in mind, would you say that it is so much better to just use the if-else instead of a switch case when dealing with ids in general?

Comment: "But what if they're just defined in the xml file?" -- I'm not sure what you are asking. Any resources (including ids) defined in XML get a generated `int` with the same name in `R.java`. The difference is whether the module containing that resource is a library module or not; if it is, the generated `int`s are not `final`. In any case, I don't think one or the other is objectively better (I personally am accustomed to using `switch`).

Comment: Sorry I meant that what if the ids are defined in an xml layout file. I'm guessing that the layout file is not a library module and is therefore declared as a final static in the `R.java` file..?

Comment: If the layout file is in a library module, then the id will not be final in the library module's `R.java` file.

Comment: This is further necessitated by gradle 8.0 and the Studio warning: "Resource IDs will be non-final by default in Android Gradle Plugin version 8.0, avoid using them in switch case statements".